# Slowing down Tkinter Canvas scrolling in Python

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter

Basically I have the following code working, but i can not find a way to slow down my canvas view dragging, as of now it's going too fast to be functional for my App. This is just a small example that shows what i'm trying to troubleshoot:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import Image, ImageTk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,root):
        frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        File = "JPG FILENAME HERE"

        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(File))
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.img, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(ALL))
        xscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        yscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        frame.pack()

        self.canvas.bind("<Button 3>",self.grab)
        self.canvas.bind("<B3-Motion>",self.drag)

    def grab(self,event):
        self._y = event.y
        self._x = event.x

    def drag(self,event):
        if (self._y-event.y < 0): self.canvas.yview("scroll",-1,"units")
        elif (self._y-event.y > 0): self.canvas.yview("scroll",1,"units")
        if (self._x-event.x < 0): self.canvas.xview("scroll",-1,"units")
        elif (self._x-event.x > 0): self.canvas.xview("scroll",1,"units")
        self._x = event.x
        self._y = event.y

root = Tk()   
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**ANSWER:**

Bryan Oakley's answer did the trick I just changed:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
```

to:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,xscrollincrement=10,yscrollincrement=10)
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the value of the `xscrollincrement` and `yscrollincrement` attributes of the canvas to something greater than zero. These settings correspond to the `units` used when you do call `xview` and `yview` with a "units" argument (eg: `self.canvas.xview("scroll",-1,"units")`.

According to the official Tk documentation, if these values are zero (the default), xview and yview adjusts *"...in units of the [x,y]ScrollIncrement option, if it is greater than zero, or in units of one-tenth the window's [width, height] otherwise"*

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what I'm doing here, but this moves more controllably, at least. First, explicitly set the canvas size:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, height=600, width=800,
                     xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set,
                     yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
```

Then, in `__init__()`, add a couple of instance variables to keep track of the current position:

```
self.pos_x = self.pos_y = 0.0
```

Then, replace the `drag` method with this:

```
def drag(self, event):
# Note canvas dimensions are used here
    self.pos_x += float(self._x-event.x) / 800.0
    self.pos_y += float(self._y-event.y) / 600.0

    if self.pos_x < 0.0: self.pos_x = 0.0
    elif self.pos_x > 1.0: self.pos_x = 1.0
    if self.pos_y < 0.0: self.pos_y = 0.0
    elif self.pos_y > 1.0: self.pos_y = 1.0

    self.canvas.xview("moveto", self.pos_x)
    self.canvas.yview("moveto", self.pos_y)

    self._x = event.x
    self._y = event.y
```

I don't know why you have to cast those numbers to float, but it doesn't work if you don't. It's brittle; if you multiply the mouse movement by anything, even just 0.99 or 1.01, the movement gets really wonky; I suspect there's some kind of feedback going on between the mouse movement and the canvas movement. It doesn't play nicely with the scroll bars, either; I suppose we'd have to update pos_x and pos_y when they're moved. As I said, don't really know what I'm doing; I haven't done much GUI programming. Anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change drag to just use the calculated value:

```
    self.canvas.yview("scroll",self._y-event.y,"units")
    self.canvas.xview("scroll",self._x-event.x,"units")
```

And change your scroll increments to 1.

Now your image should click & drag in sync with the mouse cursor, similar to popular map and document viewers.